# Zipping a file using Excel VBA produces an empty archive

Tags: vba, excel, zip

I followed [Ron de Bruins tutorial](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm) on zipping a file using Excel VBA. Here is the code I use:

```
Private Sub ZipCSVFile()
  ' FileNameCSV contains the full path to the file
  FileNameZip = FileNameCSV & ".zip"
  NewZip (FileNameZip)
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  objShell.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FileNameCSV
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  Kill FileNameCSV
End Sub

Private Sub NewZip(sPath)
  If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
  Open sPath For Output As #1
  Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
  Close #1
End Sub
```

When I run this code I will be presented with a zip file that appears to be completely empty.

One strange workaround I found was to store the CSV on the desktop and calling `.CopyHere` with `Dir(FileNameCSV)` instead of `FileNameCSV`.

Increasing the timeout doesn't help and maybe it's worth mentioning that the CSV file was saved to disk in an earlier stage of the VBA script.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `FileNameCSV`? I guess you are only including the path, without the filename.

Comment: No, it's the entire file path e.g. "C:\Users\pietz\Desktop\Folder\file.csv"

Comment: This works for me.  Is it possible your CSV file is not closed when you try to copy it?

Comment: 1. Can you try this with a different file, outside of your profile folder? 2. Do you have any other zip programs that might interfere? 3. Is the CSV file big, locked or virus-like?

Comment: Yes, I closed the file after writing. Different file outside the profile folder didn't help. I'm not sure how to tell if other zip programs might interfere. The CSV is tiny (<100KB). I went with my workaround. Store the CSV file on the Desktop and save the zip file wherever I like. Thanks all of you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Private Sub ZipCSVFile()
      ' FileNameCSV contains the full path to the file
      FileNameZip = FileNameCSV & ".zip"
      NewZip (FileNameZip)
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      objShell.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FileNameCSV
    
      '---------------------------------------------------
      'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
       On Error Resume Next
       Do Until objShell.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = 1
           Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
       Loop
       On Error GoTo 0
      '---------------------------------------------------        
    
      Kill FileNameCSV
    End Sub
```